# float.Parse returns incorrect value

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, floating-point

I have a `string X` with value `2.26`

when I parse it using `float.Parse(X)` ..it returns `2.2599999904632568`. Why so? And how to overcome this ?

But if instead I use `double.Parse(X)` it returns the exact value, i.e. `2.26`.

**EDIT:** Code

```
float.Parse(dgvItemSelection[Quantity.Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Thanks for help

Comment: you may want to watch [this](http://vimeo.com/7403673) video of Jon Skeet, he explains this too ;-)

Comment: can you post your code that produces that

Comment: `var value = decimal.Parse("2.26");`

Comment: The 'dgvItemSelection[Quantity.Index, e.RowIndex].Value' is probably not 2.26, that's all.

Comment: @Maxim: No thats not all, in that case I would not have put this question.

Comment: If you mouse over (or add to watch) `dgvItemSelection[Quantity.Index, e.RowIndex].Value` in VS debugger, what value does it show?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to limitations in the precision of floating point numbers.  They can't represent infinitely precise values and often resort to approximate values.  If you need highly precise numbers you should be using `Decimal` instead.

There is a considerable amount of literature on this subject that you should take a look at.  My favorite resource is the following

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because floats don't properly represent decimal values in base 10.

Use a Decimal instead if you want an exact representation.

[Jon Skeet on this topic](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Not all numbers can be repesented exactly in floating point. Approximations are made and when you have operation after operation on an unexact number the situation gets worse.

See this Wikipedia entry for an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

If you changed you inputs to something that can be represented exactly by floating point (like 1/8), it would work. Try the number 2.25 and it will work as expected.

The only numbers that will work exactly are numbers that can be represented by the sum of any of 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc since those numbers are represented by the binary 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, etc.

This situation happens with all floating point systems, by nature.  .Net, JavaScript, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning the best approximation to 2.26 that is possible in a `float`. You're probably getting more significant digits than that because your float is being printed as a `double` instead of a `float`.

Comment: But if the printing routine knew that it was printing a float, it should not print all of those digits. It should stop when the digits it has already produced are sufficient to distinguish that particular float from the neighboring float values.

Answer (score 0):

When I test

```
var str = "2.26";

var flt = float.Parse(str);
```

`flt` is exactly `2.26` in the VS debugger.

How do you see what it returns?

Comment: Yes this code gives perfect value. I am surprised why not in this case.